# WFFM date field - supply override for default dropdowns

Tags: wffm

Is there a way to customise the default text for the dropdowns of a Date field (`/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Simple Types/Date`) in WFFM (preferably without having to build a new rendering and ViewModel)? I'm using Sitecore 8.2 and MVC.

I decompiled the ViewModel class (`Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields.DateField, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc`) and could see only some code which can pre-populate the dropdowns with the *current date* if some flag is set on the parameters of the field item.

Comment: When you say default text, do you mean of the values on the calendar itself? Not the label for the field right...?

Comment: Yep, the initial values in the day, month and year dropdowns, not the label.